# How to throw error of ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java

This is my String:

```
        String csvFile = "Screenname,Firstname,Email,Timezone,Organization,Password,Lastname,Middlename,Gender,Birthdate\n"
            + "Test01,Test01,test01@.khalibre.com,GMT+8,Khalibre,12345,test,test,M,3/8/1980\n"
            + "Sok Dara,Dara,test02@khalibre.com,GMT-7,Khalibre,12345,Sok,Dara,,1980-d1-25\n"
            + "Test03,,test03@khalibre.com.kh,GMT+1,Khalibre,12345,test,test,M,2/2/1980\n"
            + ",Test04,test04@khalibre.com,GTM-8:00,Khalibre,12345,test,test,F,\n";
```

This Main method:

```
boolean firstLine = true;
    String[] readLineCSVs = csvFile.split("\n");
    for (String readLineCSV : readLineCSVs) {
        rows++;
        if (firstLine) {
            firstLine = false;
        } else {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Readdata rd = new Readdata();
            String[] csvData = readLineCSV.split(csvSplitBy);
            int count =0;
            while(csvData[count++]!=null){
                System.out.println(count);
            }
            System.out.println(csvData[0]);
            System.out.println(csvData[1]);
            System.out.println(csvData[2]);
            System.out.println(csvData[3]);
            System.out.println(csvData[4]);
            System.out.println(csvData[5]);
            System.out.println(csvData[6]);
            System.out.println(csvData[7]);
            System.out.println(csvData[8]);
            System.out.println(csvData[9]);
        }
```

The error show like below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
    at demo002.D2_F_003.readData(D2_F_003.java:38)
    at demo002.D2_F_003.main(D2_F_003.java:247)
```

How to throw this exception?

Comment: `throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();`

Comment: if want to throw an exception, just `throw` it!

Comment: i think everyone will missunderstand your question. you want to know how to solve this problem, because you get the exception which is thrown from your programm, right?

Comment: @kai I wonder, is he actually want to fix problem that cause that Exception?

Comment: If I had to hazard a guess, I'd say that the error is in the while loop. Without knowing what line 32 is, I can't be sure.

Comment: You haven't shown the place where the error happens.

Comment: @Gangnus: The error occur in while and after while.

Comment: You want to throw an exception so that you'll see the message like the one you have written?

Comment: In the answer you have chosen, no exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boolean firstLine = true;
String[] readLineCSVs = csvFile.split("\n");
for (String readLineCSV : readLineCSVs) {
    rows++;
    if (firstLine) {
        firstLine = false;
    } else {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Readdata rd = new Readdata();
        String[] csvData = readLineCSV.split(csvSplitBy);
        int count =0;

        try{
        while(csvData[count++]!=null){
            System.out.println(count);
        }
        System.out.println(csvData[0]);
        System.out.println(csvData[1]);
        System.out.println(csvData[2]);
        System.out.println(csvData[3]);
        System.out.println(csvData[4]);
        System.out.println(csvData[5]);
        System.out.println(csvData[6]);
        System.out.println(csvData[7]);
        System.out.println(csvData[8]);
        System.out.println(csvData[9]);
      }
      catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
   //Your Code
}catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
   //If error show 
}
catch(Exception e){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking *how to fix the error*, this looks very suspicious:

```
int count =0;
while(csvData[count++]!=null){
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

I am not sure what the null check is supposed to be for. String's split method won't return an array with null elements.

Judging from the exception message (ArrayIndexOutOfBounds 10), your array only has 10 elements, but you are trying to access index 10 (remember arrays indexes go from 0 to length - 1). You need to limit count so it does not get incremented past the last index.

This will at least stop the exception:

```
int count = 0;
while(count < csvData.length && csvData[count++] != null) {
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Comment: i assume he do the null check because he think that if count is higher then the csvData.length, the array will return null, but instead of this he is getting this exception.

Comment: @kai Yeah I was just now wondering if they thought that.